# Java Hashmap two identical objects stored seperate

Tags: java, junit, hashmap, hashcode

I overrided the hashCode and equals method of a class. I also wrote unit tests for it and it's all green. When I tested it out with a hashmap, I noticed something weird.
I created 2 identical objects:

```
obj1 = new PacmanVeld(field2);
obj2 = new PacmanVeld(field2);
```

I tested it out with this piece of code:

```
Assert.assertTrue(obj1.hashCode() == obj2.hashCode()); //works
Assert.assertTrue(obj1.equals(obj2)); //works

HashMap<PacmanVeld, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<>();
testMap.put(obj1, 5);

Assert.assertTrue(testMap.put(obj2, 7) == 5); //fails throws nullpointerexception
Assert.assertTrue(testMap.get(obj1) == 7); //fails
```

I don't understand why this won't work as I understand that in the algorithms of a HashMap, obj1 and obj2 are the same objects.

The PacmanVeld class:

```
public class PacmanVeld
{
    private Node[][] nodes;

    public PacmanVeld(char[][] veld)
    {
        this.nodes = new Node[veld.length][veld[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < veld.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < veld[i].length; j++)
            {
                switch (veld[i][j])
                {
                    case '%':
                        nodes[i][j] = new Node(i, j, NodeType.WALL);
                        break;
                    case ' ':
                        nodes[i][j] = new Node(i, j, NodeType.EMPTY);
                        break;
                    case '.':
                        nodes[i][j] = new Node(i, j, NodeType.CRUMB);
                        break;
                    case 'P':
                        nodes[i][j] = new Node(i, j, NodeType.PACMAN);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        initFinish();
        initPacman();
    }

    //getters, setters & methods

    public boolean equals(PacmanVeld p)
    {
        if (p.nodes.length != nodes.length) { return false; }
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
        {
            if (!Arrays.deepEquals(nodes[i], p.nodes[i])) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        List<Node> nodeList = getNodeList();
        return Arrays.deepHashCode(nodeList.toArray());
    }

    private void initPacman()
    {
        for (Node[] rij : this.nodes)
        {
            for (Node n : rij)
            {
                if (n.isPacman())
                {
                    pacman = n;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `PacmanVeld` class ?

Comment: And include the return from your two `testMap.put` assertions calls.

Comment: How are you getting a NPE on `testMap.put(obj2, 7) == 5`? `put` can't throw an exception according to the docs. What value is `null` exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't override the `equals()` method herited from the object class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        PacmanVeld p = (PacmanVeld)o;
        if (p.nodes.length != nodes.length) { return false; }
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
        {
            if (!Arrays.deepEquals(nodes[i], p.nodes[i])) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: As we thought: wrong `HashCode` or `Equals` implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` return `null` for new value. Your `Assert.assertTrue(testMap.put(obj2, 7) == 5);` test case throws NPE exception because, `obj2` is absent in `HashMap`. You can test with `obj1` which already put on HashMap

```
  Assert.assertTrue(testMap.put(obj2, 7) == 5); 
                  //throws NPE because obj2 is not inserted
```

Try, with obj1

```
  Assert.assertTrue(testMap.put(obj1, 7) == 5); 
          //will retrun true because, 5 is last inserted value with obj1
  Assert.assertTrue(testMap.put(obj1, 7) == 8); 
         // will retrun false because
```

Comment: Yes of course, that's true. But The first assertion throws a nullpointer exception so that's not the only problem I think...

Comment: I don't believe this to be the issue. This works perfectly fine: `Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); map.put("test", 7); System.out.println(map.put("test", 9) == 7);`

Comment: Masud is correct, those examples may work because the Integer class caches small values, but you can easily break this with large values.  It's unclear if yet another problem looms until he posts his Pacman class

Comment: @AmirAfghani: `Integer` caches until 127. It still works with 700 & 999.

Comment: All, this is not reason, I am updating my answer. It throws NPE because, obj2 is abcence at Map.

Comment: @AmirAfghani, The comparison with two `Integer` reference might be an issue if any one of them has value higher than 127. But comparison with direct constant expression(plain integer) will not be, because it will automatically unbox the `Integer`reference to `int` before the comparison. Masud's answer is wrong

Comment: I strongly doubt your edit is the source of the issue as well. The entire idea behind the question is that `obj1` and `obj2` are the same and thus it shouldn't matter which one is put in. I suspect a wrongly implemented Equals/Hashcode instead.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, please check the above answer

Comment: I have added an answer that demonstrates that a correctly implemented equals + hashcode will not cause a `null` value to return for 2 identical objects. The error must lie in his implementation of this.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your error. Since it is too long to post as a comment, I will add it as an answer and edit my post to explain your mistake once you have showed your `HashCode` and `Equals` implementation.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<MyPersonalClass, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        MyPersonalClass obj1 = new MyPersonalClass();
        obj1.someInt = 5;
        obj1.someString = "test";

        MyPersonalClass obj2 = new MyPersonalClass();
        obj2.someInt = 5;
        obj2.someString = "test";

        System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2));
        System.out.println(obj1.hashCode() == obj2.hashCode());

        map.put(obj1, 5);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map.values().toArray()));

        System.out.println(map.put(obj2, 10) == 5);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map.values().toArray()));
        System.out.println(map.get(obj1));
    }
}

class MyPersonalClass {
    public String someString;
    public int someInt;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        if(arg0 == this) { return true; }
        if(!(arg0 instanceof MyPersonalClass)) { return false; }

        MyPersonalClass obj = (MyPersonalClass) arg0;

        return obj.someString.equals(this.someString) && obj.someInt == this.someInt;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.someString.hashCode() * 37 + this.someInt;
    }
}
```

Output:

> true
>   true
>   [5]
>   true
>   [10]
>   10

Comment: @Masud: that's the entire idea behind the question. Quote from the question "I created 2 identical objects" and `Assert.assertTrue(obj1.equals(obj2)); //works`